# Fancybox display problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using FancyBox on my website and I am having a slight problem.

Fancybox works fine on Dreamweaver but it seems to break inside any browser.
I'm not a programmer and I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.

Here is the link.
http://nantelconsultant.com/plandevis.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting a large amount of network errors when I visit the website you linked. The website is unable to find the Fancybox JavaScript and CSS files on your website. Are you sure you've installed Fancybox properly, and are you sure the files are in the /fancybox/source/ directory?

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css"
jquery...box.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"
jquery...tons.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"
jquery...edia.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"
jquery...umbs.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css"
jquery...mbs.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"
jquery...ons.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css"
jquery...box.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"
jquery...tons.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"
jquery...edia.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css"
jquery...mbs.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://nantelconsultant.com/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"
jquery...umbs.js
```